# Filtering by data attribute

Tags: jquery, filter, attributes, livesearch

I'm trying to use **filter** to find table rows that contain particular values in two different data attributes (in addition to general text).

I can't seem to properly read the values from the two data attributes. Outputting the values (licData and stateData) to the console show 'undefined'. And, of course, the search fails.

**JS**

```
var $rows = $('.livesearch tr');

$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

  $rows.show().filter(function() {

    var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    var licData = $(this).find('td').attr('data-lic');
    var stateData = $(this).find('td').attr('data-state');

    console.log(text + '-' + licData + '-' + stateData + '<br>');

    if (!~stateData.indexOf(val) || !~licData.indexOf(val) || !~text.indexOf(val)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false
    }

  }).hide();
});
```

**SAMPLE TABLE ROW**

```
<tr>
  <td>Aaron</td>
  <td>Ellebrach</td>
  <td>Clerical</td>
  <td>444-444-4444</td>
  <td>Call</td>
  <td data-lic="special">C</td>
  <td data-state="state data here">CA</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var licData = $(this).find('td[data-lic]').attr('data-lic');
var stateData = $(this).find('td[data-state]').attr('data-state');
```

Your code:

```
$(this).find('td').attr('data-lic')
```

actually gives you the attribute of the first td which is obviously undefined, but when you do `$(this).find('td[data-lic]')` you are actually looking for any td with this data attribute present and hence you get the values like:-

```js
var licData = $('tr').find('td[data-lic]').attr('data-lic');
var stateData = $('tr').find('td[data-state]').attr('data-state');
console.log('licData:   ' + licData);
console.log('stateData: ' + stateData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Aaron</td>
    <td>Ellebrach</td>
    <td>Clerical</td>
    <td>444-444-4444</td>
    <td>Call</td>
    <td data-lic="special">C</td>
    <td data-state="state data here">CA</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks plalash, that worked to retrieve those values. For some reason I get an error when I try to test for indexOf(val) on those two items. Works fine when testing the 'text' variable, but stateData and licData both return: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'licData.indexOf')

Comment: Not sure what is the issue here. Could you please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). That would really helps me to figure out the issue with your code. Also, if possible post it as a new question so that others users also can have a look at it and provide solutions.

Comment: I setup on jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dmacy/148zdhm7/. If the licData and stateData are removed from the IF clause it works, and the console shows those vars getting data. But using indexOf on those two vars seems to have a problem. thx